# wishlist not showing laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm creating a wishlist ,so that user can be able to save item to wishlist. I have products table, wishlist table which has `user_id` and `product_id` columns and also I have pivot table `product_wishlist` table which has foreign key `product_id` and `wishlist_id`. The problem is it doesn't display the product information like price, name etc and it shows no errors, I don't know if my relations are wrong or there is something else, how can I  fix this ?

Wishlist.php

```
class Wishlist extends Model
{
 protected $table = "wishlist";
protected $fillable=['product_id','user_id'];

public function user(){
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function product(){
return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'product_wishlist','wishlist_id', 'product_id');
}
}
```

Product.php

```
 public function wishlist(){
    return $this-belongsToMany(Wishlist::class);
 }
```

Wishlist controller

```
 public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $wishlists = Wishlist::with('product')
    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->orderby('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(6);
    //dd($wishlists);
     return view('front.wishlist', compact('user', 'wishlists'));
}
```

Blade

```
 @foreach($wishlists as $wishlist)

 <h3 >USD {{$wishlist->name }}</h3>
 <h4 >USD {{$wishlist->price }}</h4>

  @endforeach
```

Comment: please check your syntax in `Product.php` you have `-` instead of `->` in relationship

Comment: and what gives you `dd($wishlists);`?

Comment: It gives `#relations: array:1 [▼
          "product" => Collection {#381 ▼
            #items: []
          }` empty array in product @Kusy

Comment: did you correct `product.php`?

Comment: yes I did @Kusy

Comment: Can you please check here, might be help: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: @user11710915 and you order by id is ok? do you have increments id field in your `Wishlist` model??

Comment: order by id is okay even if I remove it, still showing product as empty array @Kusy

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do

```
{{ $wishlist->product->price }}
```

As the price is an attribute on the product you need to access the product object before accessing the price.

Comment: When I dd($wishlist) it display `#relations: array:1 [▼
          "product" => Collection {#381 ▼
            #items: []
          }`  @Paradigm

Comment: I'm assuming in your pivot table there are actual relations between a wishlist and product?

Comment: I haven't created (product_wishlist) model @Paradigm

Comment: I mean in your database you should have a product_wishlist table. Do you have some records that map both to a wishlist and product?

Comment: In database product_wishlist table is empty @Paradigm

Comment: @user11710915 That is why you got empty array.

Comment: How can I connect that so that it can have records @AmitSenjaliya